# Trouble loading featured images in posts

Tags: wordpress, image, posts

Images in posts were displaying normally in while I was developing in local. Once I migrated website via all in one WP migration plugin, images won't show on posts (they are uploaded but not showing). However, those same images are normally loaded on some devices and browsers, but on some they are not showing (when I inspect element, file path is fine and image link is loaded perfectly but image itself isn't showing). For example, website is normally uploaded on my laptop on Mozilla (which is not my default web browser), but on the same laptop images from posts are not uploaded on Chrome.

This is my clients website https://mihabodytec-batajnica.rs/

Here are photos of what I am facing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is  SSL vs http issue. You need to replace all "http : / / media3.mihabodytec-batajnica.rs" with "https : / / media3.mihabodytec-batajnica.rs".  I guess it is your CDN URL.

Comment: you can see the issue/answer in the dev console: `Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, your page is loaded via HTTPS. But the image URLs in your page is loaded via HTTP.

You can easily figure out this issue viewing the Console in Developer Tools of your browser.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

What you have to do is, update the image URLs to force HTTPS. Or else, you simply change the site url to "http" (which is not recommended).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, that is the problem. How can I force images to change URLs?

Comment: Update: Found plugin for changing original media path (WP original media path). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Aleksandar Glad to know that you got it resolved! :)